# Less-rails and twitter-bootswatch-rails @imported styles not causing a LESS/CSS recompile

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, less, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm using `less-rails` and `twitter-bootswatch-rails` gems with a brand new Rails 4 app.

This sets up an `app/assets/stylesheets/cosmo/loader.css.less` which contains `@import` to all of the bootstrap less files.

`application.css` contains a  `*= require cosmo/loader`, which correctly loads all the styles.

However, when I save one of the files that are `@imported` the CSS changes are not reflected when I refresh the page; I have to edit and save `loader.css.less` for the changes to come through.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I've had the same problem with `lessphp` so my guess is the gem/compiler only watch for modifications of the main LESS file (has the timestamp changed?) and won't care about imported files by this LESS file. One solution would be to `touch` this LESS file before calling the LESS compiler, forcing a recompilation each and every time the compiler get called (each refresh I guess?). Hope sb else has a better solution ;)

Comment: This doesn't make sense, since the `less-rails` gem readme.md states Any @import to a .less file will automatically declare that file as a sprockets dependency to the file importing it. This means that you can edit imported framework files and see changes reflected in the parent during development. : https://github.com/metaskills/less-rails/#import-hooks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be resolved in the latest https://github.com/scottvrosenthal/twitter-bootswatch-rails gem release.